# Unable to understand the pointer to pointer output : 15 15

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

Could someone please help to understand on how the output of the following code is 15 15?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int **p1);
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);  //address of constant pointer p passed to function
    printf("%d\n", *p);

}
void foo(int **p1)
{
    int j = 15;
    *p1 = &j; //I don't get this line
    printf("%d\n", **p1); 
}
```

Let's assume that addr(i)=ff2, addr(pointer p)=ff4, addr(j)=ff6

i=10, j=15

p= address(i), so p= ff2

p1=address(p), so p1= ff4

Comment: Prototype for foo should be before using it.

Comment: Do you compile with warnings? At least -Wall.

Comment: @Siena  The program has undefined behavior.

Comment: `*p1 = &j` means that `*p1` stores the value of the address of the value 15. So you print `**p1` it will be 15. And since you've passed `&p` to the `foo`function `**p1`and `*p`refers to the same thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the warnings you get with strict compilation for the code which has the prototype before the calling. There might be a problem around feeding a const-involving thing to a const-free parameter.

Comment: yes, the program does throw warning. came across a quiz portal, but couldn't understand the output.

Comment: Show the warnings. Pretty please.

Comment: Using this IDE. 
http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/4l7xu0

Comment: You need to either put foo before main or predeclare it.

Comment: Please understand, the answer to "Why strange behaviour?" of any program wiht undefined behaviour is "Because undefined behaviour." So if you want an interesting answer you have to get rid of the UB by editing your code. @VladfromMoscow has noted UB for your code. I guess he thinks of similar things as I hint at with the prototype and the warnings. So please, please, please show the warnings and your thoughts on them. And do so directly, text here, not an external link. If you cannot demonstrate your question/problem without UB, then the answer will stay "UB".

Comment: @Yunnosch I have edited the code. It's running without any warning now. However, the intent was to understand the address assignment to pointer-to-pointer variable P1

Comment: there is nothing to understand from this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the undefined behavior<sup>1</sup> for a minute, here's what's happening, or at least the *intent* of the example.

First, you have an integer object `i` containing the value `10`:

```
   +----+
i: | 10 |
   +----+
```

You create a pointer object `p` that points to `i`:

```
   +---+          +----+
p: |   | ----> i: | 10 |
   +---+          +----+
```

You pass the address of `p` to `foo`.  The function parameter `p1` points to `p`:

```
    +---+          +---+          +----+
p1: |   | ----> p: |   | ----> i: | 10 |
    +---+          +---+          +----+
```

Within `foo` you create the integer object `j` with the value `15`:

```
   +----+
j: | 15 |
   +----+
```

Now, here's the fun part - you set `p` to point to `j` by *dereferencing* `p1` and assigning the address of `j` to the result.  `*p1 == p`, so by extension `*p1 = &j` is effectively the same as writing `p = &j`. After that line, you have the following situation:

```
    +---+          +---+          +----+
p1: |   | ----> p: |   | ----> j: | 15 |
    +---+          +---+          +----+
```

That's why printing the value of `**p1` in `foo` outputs 15.  `p1 == &p`, so `*p1 == p == &j`, so `**p1 == *p == j == 15`.

Now, when the function `foo` exits, `j` *ceases to exist*, so `p` is no longer a *valid* pointer - it no longer points to an active object. Since it's no longer valid, the behavior on dereferencing it is *undefined*; your code may crash, or it may corrupt data, or it may appear to work as expected, or do something else entirely.

The *logical* object `j` ceased to exist, but the memory it used to occupy is still there, and will contain the last thing written to it, which is the value `15`.  As long as nothing else overwrites that memory, you'll continue to see `*p == 15`. But this behavior is not guaranteed, and you should not rely on it.

That's far from the only problem with this code, as Vlad and others have pointed out. But again, that's basically what's happening.

---

1. Including but not limited to: type mismatch between the implicit *declaration* of `foo` (function returning `int`) and the explicit *definition* of `foo` (function returning `void`), attempting to write to a `const`-qualified pointer through a non-`const` expression and dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Comment: thanks John! concept very clearly explained

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior.

To understand what is wrong in the program let's introduce a typedef for the pointer type.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * T;

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;
    const T p = &i;

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

As it is seen the variable `p` is declared with the qualifier const.

Now let's try to add the function `foo`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * T;

void foo( T *pp )
{

}

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;
    const T p = &i;

    foo( &p );

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

Oops, the compiler issued an error

```
prog.c:15:7: error: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
  foo( &p );
       ^
prog.c:5:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int * const*’
 void foo( T *pp )
```

Indeed the variable `p` is declared with the qualifier `const`

```
    const T p = &i;
```

So a pointer to the variable must have the type `const T *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * T;

void foo( const T *pp )
{

}

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;
    const T p = &i;

    foo( &p );

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

Now if to dereference the parameter `pp` within the function we get a constant object that may not be changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int * T;

void foo( const T *pp )
{
    int j = 15;
    *pp = &j;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;
    const T p = &i;

    foo( &p );

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

So the compiler again will issue an error

```
prog.c: In function ‘foo’:
prog.c:8:6: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*pp’
  *pp = &j;
      ^
```

And moreover you are trying to assign the address of a local variable that after exiting the function will be invalid. So even if the pointer was not constant in any case the program had undefined behavior.

EDIT:
After you seriously changed your program (that is a bad idea) in the question removing the `const` qualifier from the declaration of the pointer `p` nevertheless as I already said the program has undefined behavior because the pointer is assigned with the value of a local variable. So the pointer will have invalid value because the variable is not alive any more after exiting the function though you can get an expected result.

```
void foo(int **p1)
{
    int j = 15;
    // Assigning the original variable p pointed to by the parameter p1
    // the address of the local variable j.
    *p1 = &j; //I don't get this line
    printf("%d\n", **p1); 
}
```

As for this statement

```
*p1 = &j;
```

then the pointer p1 points to the original pointer `p`. So dereferencing the pointer `p1` you get the original pointer `p` to which the address of the local variable `j` is assigned.

Comment: Code by OP has no `const` anymore (sorry for probably causing the target to move). You might want to comment, or maybe adapt the good answer.